# Why angular2 sources don't have typescript files in sources

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've just downloaded angular2 files through npm and I'm looking at sources and there's no `ts` files there:

[image]

Why is it so? I've read that angular2 is written in typescript.

Comment: Your image shows a number of files ending in *.ts. ts=type script.

Comment: It's worthwhile reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38515955/4045532)

Comment: @Corporalis, thanks, that's helpful

Comment: @BetaRide those are .d.ts, those are only type definitions.

Comment: And guess what language is used to write this defintions?